# Como validar que una cadena tenga sentido en android? (java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo un método para validar que los campos no sean vacíos, pero ahora necesito validar que el usuario ingrese texto con sentido o coherencia es decir que no solo escriba por ejemplo **smdfmasdmf**:

```
  public boolean validaData() {
       boolean validate = false;
       String propietario = edtPropietario.getText().toString().trim();

       if (propietario.length()>5){
           Log.i(TAG,"mayor a 5");
           validate = true;
       }
       return validate;
 }
```

Con lo anterior aseguro que escriba 5 caracteres pero podrian ser **mjfgt** sin tener sentido

Comment: Creo que la forma más sencilla seria tener un diccionario en la APP para contrastarlo así te aseguras que la palabra sea coherente. Aunque no sea la más optima.

Comment: Casi mejor intentar montar un servicio que contraste con algún diccionario online. Tener el diccionario en la aplicación puede ser pesado

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev es cierto lo que comenta todo depende de dónde quieras hacer el gaste de recursos en peticiones al servicio online o en el storage del dispositivo.

Comment: ¿Cuál sería tu criterio para decir que una cadena tiene sentido?

Comment: Si @solamente, tienes razón, es cuestión de decidir dónde gastar recursos. También existe la solución mixta - consumir servicio y cachear datos en local. Las palabras más usadas estarán en cache y así se ahorran sucesivas peticiones. Cuestión de diseño.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo recomendable es tener un catalogo donde se definan cuales son las palabras consideradas como validas.

Puedes usar un archivo conteniendo estas palabras o consumir un API que tenga este diccionario y que soporte palabras en idioma español.

Revisa:
[Las 10 mejores API de diccionarios que deberías usar en este momento](https://blog.rapidapi.com/dictionary-apis/) (inglés).
También puedes revisar en la lista de APIs libres:
https://rapidapi.com/collection/list-of-free-apis

Un ejemplo similar a la consulta de una API, sería usando un archivo .txt que contiene el catalogo de palabras permitidas (almacenado en `res/raw/`):

```
mamuta
minodora
ioana
pisicuta
libro
igmer
libreta
bandera
chopostripis
australopithecus
abstraction
```

Este sería el método para validar si la palabra esta definida en el catalogo:

```
private  boolean isValidWord(String word){
    try {

        //Longitud de la palabra mayor a 5.
        if(word.length()>5){
            return false;
        }

        String line = "";
        //Obtiene palabras de archivo .txt.
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.words);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        Set<String> wordsSet = new HashSet<>();
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            wordsSet.add(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        //Revisa si la palabra esta contenida en el catalogo.
        if(wordsSet.contains(word.toLowerCase())){
            return true; //Existe, es palabra válida.
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Llamando este método determinarías si la palabra es válida:

```
System.out.println("¿Es \"Igmer\" palabra válida?" + isValidWord("Igmer"));
```